# ClassNotFoundException for javax.servlet.Filter from a JAR file

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have created a filter by implementing `javax.servlet.Filter` :

```
public class WrappingFilter implements Filter {
  //stuff here
}
```

I have created a JAR file of this filter along with some other required classes. This jar file is added in WEB-INF/lib

In my web application's web.xml I have defined `<filter>`:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>test</filter-name>
  <filter-class >com.ex.web.WrappingFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>test</filter-name>
  <url-pattern >/*</url-pattern>    
</filter-mapping>
```

But after starting tomcat I am getting error `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:`. I double checked that jar file is having class file at the exact same path I mentioned in `<filter-class >`. Is it like, filter can't be referred from jar file?

Comment: Looks like your JAR file is not in your folder WEB-INF/lib of your project or Tomcat is not recognizing it in your WAR (which will be really odd). Make sure your WAR is being generated with the necessary files inside it.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yes, it's confirmed that WAR file is having this jar in WEB-INF/lib location. Even running project in STS is also giving the same problem. In sts I checked that jar file is deployed in correct location.

Comment: Can you please provide the stacktrace in the logs?

Comment: Create a separate JAR file for your filter and put it inside tomcat/lib folder instead of your application's WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: Please list all the imports that your filter uses. Are their jars also included in WEB-INF/lib?